# QQ plot distribution check

Tags: python, data-science, distribution

I want to check if a distribution is log normal or not by using qq plot. So for convenience I am creating a 
lognormal distribution using `stats` and checking it in probplot by using the dist function. But still I am not getting my points on 45 degree line i.e the qq plot showing my z is not lognormal. Why?I am new here any help would be much appreciated. Here my code

```
z=stats.lognorm.rvs(2.5,size=500)
stats.probplot(z,dist=stats.lognorm, sparams=(2.5,),plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

and this is my result: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHhK7.png)

Comment: This is an interesting statistical observation, but a bit off-topic for stackoverflow. You will probably get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a statistical artifact of the exponential nature of the log-normal distribution. Note the large gap between the points on the far right-hand side of the plot. Interestingly, even with large sample sizes, it doesn't seem to be a good visual fit.

But if you first take the logarithm, you will see that the randomly sampled points are indeed normally distributed (on a log scale).

```
from scipy import stats 
import pylab
import numpy as np

z=np.log(stats.lognorm.rvs(2.5,size=500))
stats.probplot(z,dist=stats.norm, sparams=(0,2.5),plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

So programmatically, your SciPy code seems to be working correctly. For the mathematical reason, probably best to ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes you are right i posted it on stack exchange.posted in a hurry,did not see was logged into stackoverflow. Bdw the code is right i think the problem is with shape factor have to wait to get the correct answer thanks anyway :)